# Winning a simultaneous coin flip battle

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Assume my friend and I both have one H/T coin each and flipping them simultaneously.

What is the probability of me flipping 4 times Heads before he flips 2 times Heads? (Not consecutively)

What is the general case of this problem of me flipping X times Heads before he flips Y times Heads?